# Making a maven build incremental by using takiri-lifecycle-plugin

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, devops

I added `takiri-lifecycle-plugin` and disabled `maven-complier-plugin` on our parent `pom` in a multi-moduled project, so it will be built incrementally:

```
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>io.takari.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>takari-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>

       </pluginManagement>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.takari.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>takari-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
      </pluginManagement>
```

but I'm keep getting the following message again:

```
[INFO] --- takari-lifecycle-plugin:1.12.2:compile (compile) @ infra ---
[INFO] Previous incremental build state does not exist, performing full build
[INFO] Compiling 217 sources to /home/shmulik/clients/root/java/infra/target/classes
[INFO] Compiled 217 out of 217 sources (4277 ms)
```

Which I guess, indicates that it didn't. Am I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

As the plugin already stated it is a life cycle which means you have to configure the takari-lifecycle-plugin like this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>io.takari.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>takari-lifecycle-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The important part is the line `<extensions>true</extensions>` otherwise the life cycle will not being activated.

You can also read that in the [book of takari](http://takari.io/book/40-lifecycle.html)

Comment: khmarbaise, thanks for your comment but I did added `<extensions>true</extensions>` when trying to solve it and it didn't work either. The plugin does run but it doesn't collect data which is needed for it to decide whether or not it should compile.

Comment: Was not contained in the original post. Have you correctly done the configuration of the plugin outside pluginManagement? How do you call maven ?

Comment: I've added my minimalist `plugins` section at the post. I'm running maven using `mvn clean verify -Denv.ROOT_DIR=/home/shmulik/clients/root -Ptest -pl fe -am` or `mvn clean install -Denv.ROOT_DIR=/home/shmulik/clients/root -Ptest -pl fe -am`. Thanks again.

Comment: @TidharKleinOrbach Unfortunately, I didn't. Please let me know if you succeed.